# Multiple loops in flat database

Tags: php

http://projects.ourplanet.tk/junetxtdb/

http://code.google.com/p/junetxtdb/ in cms (LekkiCMS)

Now my question is how change this code :

```
$query = $db->select('wizyty');
foreach($query  as $record) {
    $idz = $record['pro'];
    $query2 = $db->select('wizyty_zabiegi',array('id'=>$idz));
    foreach($query2  as $record2) {
        $record2['name'];
    }
}
```

Every table has lots of values

table wizyty has organized this way

```
ID"PID"pro"date"time"value1"value2
1"1"2"2020-12-30"12:00"1"2
2"1"1"2020-05-30"12:00"1"2
```

and table wizyty_zabiegi this way

```
ID"name"TIMES"HOW
1"Masaż stóp"25"100
2"Masaż nóg"25"100
```

i use even for (valuepro = valueid)
but this show only good in first result
third, five , six etc result dont show correctly

thank you ;)

i know in mysql i have join but in this project i dont have it ;(

Comment: My anti-virus just reported that your first link leads to a blacklisted site.

Comment: Also, your second link is an archived project last touched 10 years ago. The chance of someone finding this question and knowing how it works are pretty low.

Answer (score 0):

i wrote this question and i found solution hahah

```
$is= $record['zabieg'] -1;
                    $query2 = $db->select('wizyty_zabiegi');
                    $result .= $query2[$is]['nazwa'];
```

thanks for everything even for reading this messages